# Python: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: android, python, json, charm-crypto

I am developing a charm library cryptography program. So I create some files during a crypto proccess:

This is the first form of the file:

{'S': [2529547354104704434488815336454882971551258253442172664909262664872262308641828657180425763251762799434214676246389229439927937673355984381661698478673721, 7884939579955751675768865466204184622801192045100545653347054876204470548009966239814439012606265136851937377969101594874038755793215125888772591665445255], 'C': {'A': [4301049431384134767239465358013758632794165564671693037571560456238252229587135559146275523146001114893529229447189748225061786239679120035209122482303857, 6306063077181251815212984680976900836993638595149349533803859644566294454808531174150325672959842332667803658638420955016836702483346961178326399241054652], 'C': , 'B': [6352998185563729165088467393939385610730624735454084048756301367631062390264309076917543868773558763863051002854802153320010790248052150717986667832046361, 3232330908513706152298027832774230059780104552931278853973284657391134433148157845009937793037162112475438532301331093442728792648078952136809080410765988]}}

Here I modify it with objectToByte function of charm crypto library:

```
        f = open( rootdir + '/sym_ciphertexts/'+client_mac+'.enc', 'w')
        f.write( objectToBytes(sym_key_ciphertext['S'], group)+"\n")
        f.write( objectToBytes(sym_key_ciphertext['C']['A'], group)+"\n")
        f.write( objectToBytes(sym_key_ciphertext['C']['B'], group)+"\n")
        f.write( str(sym_key_ciphertext['C']['C']))
        f.close()
```

And I receive the following file:

eJxTMrQKzfdPtEzOcS8Nzkg3Ta7wdHL1zHJ0cvROSdMucMzKC/RJNnEriQg30Q8OM/SM0jf1KKoqNAsxNAkNLS7MyPOKDMj2tjAsNTEN1Q511Xb0cwwoNkxOdHS0VQIASnccfw==
    eJxTMrRK9nc1KMzNL7VILQopN/VN982tDAjN8y9IrnL2SDUwzvWu9HMz0Tfy8w1x1891Sy10TylI9QpPDA4wCzc3SUt2L0vz8qgMrDJMyc8xrPILSQ5IMXcrDHS0VQIAhe8eSQ==
    eJwlzMkOQ0AAANB/cXUQpogmPZgYy2CCsbS92dqYKiaWqq/voe8DngDODPGWbebzS19JoNdxbOY60XqnhOt7BgiLjizv/iHX9tLhqGIS94oqj9wuvlE0TKMx4aGxCqZmwWEQtNkTW+YMxB8I00SkPZWk/wybEIbgMWZVSjYk0nuODtkCwTyUHHUj5khj6tpsLiQa9AE9NZ5ZtuTq7IoZqRwr3kX4AfuIOP8=
    670859917002753633409302654664271647328249631254

In order to receive the starting file again I use the following code:

```
f = open( rootdir + '/sym_ciphertexts/'+client_mac+'.enc', 'r')
json_data = json.loads(f.read())
f.close()
C_ = {'A':bytesToObject(json_data['C']['A'] ,group), 'B':bytesToObject(json_data['C']['B'] ,group), 'C':integer(int(json_data['C']['C']))} 
c = {'S': bytesToObject(json_data['S'], group) ,'C':C_}
print c
```

But I get the following Error:

```
    Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.1.8', 52588)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 328, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "server.py", line 228, in do_GET
    json_data = json.loads(f.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I am doing all this modifications because I must transfer the files between devices.
Any advice would be helpful and deeply appreciated...

Comment: The input is not in valid JSON format, each `'` should be replaced with `"` and `'C': , 'B':` should probably be `"B":`

Answer (score 0):

The string you are loading with `json.loads()` is not valid json.  Try writing it using `json.dump()` or `json.dumps()` instead of `f.write()`

Answer (score 0):

I am using **pickle** module to serialize/unserialize data to be able to transfer raw Python objects:

```
import pickle

def ObjectToString(obj):
    return pickle.dumps(obj, protocol=2)

def StringToObject(inp):
    return pickle.loads(inp)
```

You can pass your json dictionary (or plain text if you need to transfer file content) to ObjectToString on ***source*** device, move the data to another device, unpack with StringToObject and got the original object on ***receiver***.